# FormHelper strange input CakePhp

Tags: forms, cakephp, checkbox

I'm in trouble with the FormHelper.

I had my first model "Game". It's look like that :

```
 class Game extends AppModel{    
 public $hasMany = array('gamesauthors','gameseditors','gamesillustrators','gamesgametypes');
 public $hasAndBelongsToMany = 
        array("Author" => 
            array('joinTable' => 'gamesauthors'),
        "Editor" =>
            array('joinTable' => 'gameseditors'),
        "Illustrator" =>
            array("joinTable" => 'gamesillustrators'),
        "Gametype" =>
            array('joinTable' => 'gamesgametypes'));    
 public $belongsTo = array('Collection','Distributor');
 }
```

When I try to make the "Gametypes" appared with checkbox with that code :

```
    <?= $this->Form->input('gametypes', array("label" => "Type(s) de jeu:", 'option' => $types, 'multiple' => 'checkbox')); ?>
```

It's a text form instead of the checkbox...

I realy don't understand. It's the only thing can't working. All the other model (author, editor...) it's more than right...  I checked all my code more than many times. It's exactly the same as the other models...

I can post more informations if needed (var_dump, debug, anything!).

If someone had a idea... Please!

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using ' and " in an array, which could be causing issues

```
$this->Form->input('gametypes', array(
    'label' => 'Type(s) de jeu:',
    'option' => $types,
    'multiple' => 'checkbox'));
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: Nop... Same problem. I realy can't understand this. All other field have exactly the same code. Only this is doing stupid things.
Thanks by the way

Comment: Are you passing the values for $multiples from the controller to the view using $this->set(); ? Can you post the controller code and specify which function you are calling?

Comment: `code` public function edit($id = false){               
        $collections = $this->Game->Collection->find('list');
        $distributors = $this->Game->Distributor->find('list');        
        $authors = $this->Game->Author->find('list');
        $editors = $this->Game->Editor->find('list');
        $types = $this->Game->Gametype->find('list');
        $illustrators = $this->Game->Illustrator->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('collections','distributors','authors','editors','types','illustrators'));

    }

`code`

Here my function in my controller

Comment: I finaly find a solution!!! I just rename the "gametypes" to "types"... Stupid thing. Thanks for helping !!